# Intellij Idea 2019.1.3 cannot run ScalaTests

Tags: scala, gradle, intellij-idea, scalatest

I have a small Scala project and I am building it with Gradle. My IDE is Intellij Idea. I have configured the `build.gradle` file by adding a `spec` task for running the tests without needing to add the `@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])` annotation on every test class and it works fine when I run gradle from the command line.

But IDEA does not recognize this task and cannot run any tests. When I try to run a Test class in IDEA I get the error `No tests found for given includes:[chapter2.polymorphic.SequencesTest](filter.includeTestsMatching)`

Is there some configuration that is missing for IDEA to run the tests according to the `build.gradle` file?

The whole project code can be found in [github](https://github.com/axthosarouris/functional)

Below is the `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'scala'
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
}

apply plugin: 'scala'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

wrapper {
    gradleVersion = "5.4.1"
    distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL
}

def scalaVersion = "2.12"
dependencies {

    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:${scalaVersion}.8"

    // Use Scalatest for testing our library
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.scalatest:scalatest_${scalaVersion}:3.0.8"
    // Need scala-xml at test runtime
    testRuntime "org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_${scalaVersion}:1.2.0"

    //html test reports
    testCompile group: 'org.pegdown', name: 'pegdown', version: '1.6.0'

}

task spec(dependsOn: ['testClasses'], type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'org.scalatest.tools.Runner'
    args = ['-R', "build/classes/scala/test", '-o', '-h', 'build/tests/reports']
    classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath

}
test.dependsOn(spec)
```

Comment: Please post some minimum reproducible example. The best is to upload your project somewhere.

Comment: Added the github link